# Why permitAll() returns 403 spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a method for persisting user details in the database and i also have a controller which is exposed at the endpoint /register. I wanted to make the /register endpoint available to all. I have used spring security and gave permit all for the /register end point.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(
                request -> request.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain or help me out why permitAll is not working in my case. As per the code i have written the /register end point should return the user details but it returns 403. The /register endpoint is a rest endpoint which takes the user details as input and return the user details as output once the detal is persisted to the database.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationController(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> registerNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users users) throws EmailAlreadyExistsException {
        Users usersDetails = userDetailsService.processRegistration(users);
        log.info("{}, Information: Successfully persisted new user",this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usersDetails,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are calling the url via curl or postman. You must then disable CSRF or use a GET mapping instead.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(
            request -> request.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
}
```

Comment: Why does this happen? What design choice leads to this? I am assuming an API which serves both a frontend and is used as raw curl calls should work seamlessly.